# number in range () code not returning expected result

Tags: python, range

I'm learning Python and am playing with simple code writing and if-elif-else statements at the moment. **I have this code block which is always returning the else statement**, even if I put in a number between 1 and 30.

```
elif door == "3":
        print "This is a winning treasure room, congratulations!"
        print "Pick a number between 1 and 30"

        number = raw_input ("> ")

        if number in range (1,10):
            print "that's a number between 1 and 10"

        elif number in range (11, 20):
            print "that's a number between 11 and 20"

        elif number in range (21, 30):
            print "that's a number between 21 and 30"

        else:
            print "that's not a number we asked for"
```

I've also then tried:

```
elif door == "3":
        print "This is a winning treasure room, congratulations!"
        print "Pick a number between 1 and 30"

        number = raw_input ("> ")

        if number == number in range (1,10):
            print "that's a number between 1 and 10"

        elif number == number in range (11, 20):
            print "that's a number between 11 and 20"

        elif number == number in range (21, 30):
            print "that's a number between 21 and 30"

        else:
            print "that's not a number we asked for"
```

I also tried:

```
 if number == x in range (1, 10):
```

But of course x isn't defined which comes up as an error.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Python! I guess the number when read from input is a string, try `int(number)` also a good opportunity to learn robust input handling with try and except ;-)

Comment: "that's a number between 1 and 10" not including 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`raw_input()` converts the input into string. You need to convert it into integer.

```
number = int(raw_input ("> "))
```

**raw_input()**:

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

from [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Comment: Excellent, I've learnt about this but it didn't occur to me. I also realised that a range of course ignores the last number in the range so picking '10' will skip to the else statement as well. Will work on this now. Thanks again